# Run time exception (Java Version Issue)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, java-8, hana

I tried to start with new JSP hello world program in eclipse neon - which runs in java version 8. I did remember the code was working few days back.

Now,If i run in **java web server** in local. I see below message

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If I try to run thru SAP HCP server, I get below message

```
Problem during deploymentJava version [8] is not compatible with the currently specified runtime; use runtime neo-java-web 2.x or 3.x
Java version [8] is not compatible with the currently specified runtime; use runtime neo-java-web 2.x or 3.x
```

Appreciate if any thoughts on how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: Did you google the error message?

Answer (score 1):

> You should use Java Web Tomcat 7 runtime type in Eclipse with the Java Web Tomcat 7 SDK.

[Source](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3857381)

Comment: Awesome... I changed the runtime config... it works... Thanks a lot....

Comment: @user7896515 in the future, you can save a lot of time by googling the error message.